# Can't shutdown through terminal

Tags: 13.04, command-line

When ever i use the following

```
sudo shutdown now

sudo reboot

sudo shutdown -h
```

my laptop goes on halt , what exactly it is, sometime they work but not all the time .. why is it so..??

is there something wrong with my Input Command or Installation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

All the available options for `shutdown` command are

```
-r     Requests that the system be rebooted after it has been brought down.
-h     Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the system.
-H     Requests that the system be halted after it has been brought down.
-P     Requests that the system be powered off after it has been brought down.
-c     Cancels a running shutdown.
-k     Only send out the warning messages and disable logins, do not actually bring the system down.
```

Comment: yeah thanks bro, for this descriptive explanation..

Comment: You're welcome @Sushantp606

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo shutdown -h now` command to shutdown quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
init 0
```

init process shutdown all of the spawned processes/daemons as written in the init files